Mandaenism and Christianity
This paper The Priority of Mandaean Tropes Generally Considered Derivative of Christian and Islamic Influences seems to show that Mandaenism influenced a lot of Christianity and Islam, as we see many parallels between the texts, instead of the reverse claim (which the paper calls "standard model") that Islam and Christianity influenced the Ginza Rabba text.
How would Christianity evaluate whether this claim is correct?

that is a 20 page paper. Can you include a summary of main points? what texts are you referencing?

I would say only the 3rd page and last 2 pages are necessary ( although quoting them would also make this post extensively long)

I would like to know if there have been academics who have spoken on the relation between the quran as the Ginza rabba , if you know of any I'd like a link

this site doesn't generally deal with questions about islam

Your question is likely to be closed for the reason given by depperm. However, if you edit this question to ask for the Christian view of John the Baptist you might get some answers that will help to inform you.

@Tahir says "quoting them would also make this post extensively long" — Reading the linked item requires signing into their system. That makes it inconvenient, and possibly violates the reader's privacy. More significantly for you, the linked page itself might go away at any time, making this question incomprehensible for future readers. Providing brief quotations of the essential parts (enough so that we know the point) would greatly improve this question.

This question is almost voted closed for lack of focus (4 votes at this time), I made an edit to clarify that this is a Christian apologetics question and a comparative-religion in the hope to save it from closure.  I think this is quite a worthwhile question, and @Lesley provides a matching answer.

@Tahir It's a good convention in Christianity.SE to lessen the burden of people who are trying to answer your question in matters not that familiar (such as a rare heresy, i.e. a variation of Gnosticism) to summarize the relevant parts of the paper (that you already identified as 3rd page and last 2 pages).  This is also the opportunity for helping you communicate more clearly the focus of your question.  I tried to edit it to save it from closure, but I'm not going to summarize it for you, as it is the responsibility of the OP.

Before any person can attempt to answer your question, you need to clarify what it is you seek to know.  Are you asking if Mandaenism influenced Christianity and Islam?  Or are you asking something different?  Until such clarification is given, we need to understand what Mandaenism is.
•   Mandaeans believe that John the Baptist was the final and most important prophet.
•   They may have been among the earliest adherents of Gnosticism.
Right away it becomes obvious that Christianity can have nothing to do with Mandaenism.
This article goes into more detail:

Mandaeism, sometimes also known as Nasoraeanism or Sabianism, is a Gnostic, monotheistic and ethnic religion with Greek, Iranian, and Jewish influences.  Its adherents, the Mandaeans, revere Adam, Abel, Seth, Enos, Noah, Shem, Aram, and especially John the Baptist. Mandaeans consider Adam, Seth, Noah, Shem and John the Baptist prophets, with Adam being the founder of the religion and John being the greatest and final prophet.

Neither Christianity nor Islam believe that John the Baptist was the greatest and final prophet.
